# Is there a replacement for the int64 package?

Tags: r

Looks like `int64` has been deprecated.  So what is the official/best way to get well-behaved 64-bit ints in R?

I don't want to use `gmp` or any kind of big integer package.  Are 64-bit ints built into R by default now/soon?  I'm still running 3.0.1.  Maybe I just need to upgrade.

Comment: Perhaps [bit64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new package 'bit64' that promises to be way faster than 'int64'.

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-packages/2012/001287.html) is the author of bit64 (Jens Oehlschlägel) giving a short explanation of the advantages of the new package. The vignette with full details is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf).

Let's hope someone comes up with a more objective and reproducible benchmark comparison of the two packages.